# Unable to access Docker Nanoserver container web app

Tags: docker, nano-server

This question is similar to others on the topic of Windows networks and how they relate to Docker containers, but I can't seem to find a solution to my exact problem.

I am setting up a Docker container for a new pre-build pre-published .NET Core 1.1 application. I have a Dockerfile which builds the app into a nanoserver/.NET Core 1.1 enabled image, yet I am NOT able to access the running application from the Windows host.

Using: Docker for Windows 17.0.31-ce-win10 (11972) on a Windows 10 Pro VM hosted by macOS/vmWare Fusion 8.5.1.

Given the following `Dockerfile`:

`FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime-nanoserver
WORKDIR \app
COPY \out .
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]`

If I use the command `docker run {image} -P 5000:5000` I get the following output (from a .NET Core 1.1 Hello World app):

`Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\app
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.`

Then, in another terminal window, I issue the following command:

`docker inspect {container-name}` where I get this notable output:

`"Networks": {
    "nat": {
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": null,
        "NetworkID": "246469d0fe2936d87c5a923
        "EndpointID": "2401e38f20539ac9fe562e
        "Gateway": "172.20.64.1",
        "IPAddress": "172.20.76.30",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:33:3e:7a"
    }
}`

I'm not able to access the web application using the following locations:

`localhost:5000`, `172.20.76.30:80`, `172.20.76.30:5000`

Curiously, however, if I `docker run microsoft/iis` I'm able to access `{container's IP}:80`.

Given the above, what am I doing wrong that is causing my web app container to be inaccessible to the Windows VM host? I'm able to `ping 172.20.76.30` with results, and my container is able to `ping 172.20.64.1` (its Gateway IP which corresponds with the Windows VM host) but that's as far as I've been able to get in confirming the path between the two network hosts.

Finally, I'll conclude with the observation that the app runs perfectly fine on the Windows VM. I'm able to issue the exact same command `dotnet WebApi.dll` directly and access the site using `localhost:5000` in Chrome.

Comment: What driver is the "nat" network using? Bridge? Host? Null?

Comment: The nat network is setup in Hyper-V as an Internal Network. Please let me know if you're looking for more detail than this (and where I can find it.) Thanks for asking!

Comment: Ok the docker virtual lan should be internal. If you do the `docker network ls` command from the terminal and see what driver it lists under your "nat" network name. I believe you want to be using the `bridge` driver

Comment: `docker network ls` produces the following: 

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
1c086d38347a        nat                 nat                 local
3e8fc51bda59        none                null                local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. I swapped the base image for the `Dockerfile` from `FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1-runtime-nanoserver` to `FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.2-nanoserver` and suddenly everything worked.

I'm a bit surprised this works since I can run `dotnet WebApi.dll` from my local machine without a problem, but I'm just glad I found an image/tag that works!

Answer (score 2):

If it started working because you switched to the `aspnetcore` image then it is probably a port mapping issue rather than a networking one. The aspnetcore base image sets the ASP.NET Core environment variable that tells Kestrel to listen on port 80, and not bind to `localhost:5000`. The key in that last statement is localhost, unless you say otherwise Kestrel only works for local traffic. Traffic from your host is not local, so it wouldn't have worked.

If you want to use the `dotnet` image instead of the `aspnetcore` one for some reason then you can set the `ASPNETCORE_URL` environment variable to something like `http://+:5000` or whatever port you want.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. I didn't realize Kestrel only worked for local traffic - that explains why it wouldn't work despite port mappings in my `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*

There is definitely a limitation currently with windows.

Looks like its bad news according to blog link: [Docker Loop Back For Windows Containers](https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/)

Currently, window containers are only accessible via their virtual IP address. Loop back access is not supported yet.

Comment: Actually, the NAT network is using the "nat" driver, according to the output I provided in your question to my OP. When I issue `docker network rm nat` I get `Error response from daemon: none is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed.`

Comment: When I try to create a new network (.e. g `docker network create net1`) I get `Error response from daemon: plugin not found`

Comment: I am going to run this dockerfile now and see if i have the same issue. I have not seen that error before when creating a network.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you sir! It goes without saying that being able to add/remove a network is probably unrelated to the `Dockerfile` but I do want to ensure no stone is left untouched in troubleshooting my networking woes at large!

Comment: I just noticed your edit to your answer. I was already aware of this article before my OP. The virtual IP is the IP returned from `docker inspect {containerName}` correct? If so, then accessing `{containerName}:port` should yield the application. As I mentioned elsewhere, I'm able to run `microsoft/iis` and fetch the IIS default page on the respective container IP/port so I don't think this is related to Windows' networking design (yet.)